# Validation loss oscillates a lot, validation accuracy > learning accuracy, but test accuracy is high. Is my model overfitting?

Tags: optimization, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

1. I am training a model, and using the original learning rate of the author (I use their github too), I get a validation loss that keeps oscillating a lot, it will decrease but then suddenly jump to a large value and then decrease again, but never really converges as the lowest it gets is 2 (while training loss converges to 0.0 something - much below 1)

At each epoch I get the training accuracy and at the end, the validation accuracy. Validation accuracy is always greater than the training accuracy.

When I test on real test data, I get good results, but I wonder if my model is overfitting. I expect a good model's val loss to converge in a similar fashion with training loss, but this doesn't happen and the fact that the val loss oscillates to very large values at times worries me.

2. Adjusting the learning rate and scheduler etc etc, I got the val loss and training loss to a downward fashion with less oscilliation, but this time my test accuracy remains low (as well as training and validation accuracies)

I did try a couple of optimizers (adam, sgd, adagrad) with step scheduler and also the pleateu one of pytorch, I played with step sizes etc. but it didn't really help, neither did clipping gradients.

1. Is my model overfitting?
2. If so, how can I reduce the overfitting besides data augmentation?
3. If not (I read some people on quora said it is nothing to worry about, though I would think it must be overfitting), how can I justify it? Even if I would get similar results for a k-fold experiment, would it be good enough? I don't feel it would justify the oscilliating. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The training loss at each epoch is *usually* computed on **the entire training set**.
The validation loss at each epoch is *usually* computed on **one minibatch of the validation set**, so it is normal for it to be more noisey.
**Solution:** You can report the *Exponential Moving Average* of the validation loss across different epochs to have less fluctuations.

---

It is not overfitting since your validation accuracy is not less than the training accuracy. In fact, it sounds like your model is underfitting since your validation accuracy > training accuracy.

Comment: Thanks! reporting exponential moving average sounds like a good idea.

Comment: but doesn't it also mean it is not good at generalizing if result is noisy? I suppose there is room for improvement like you said, for underfitting.

Comment: The result is (most likely) noisey because you're getting the validation loss on a small subsample of the validation set (instead of using the whole validation set every time). This is the problem and it has nothing to do with how good your model is. When you randomly get a subsample from the validation set for measuring the loss, you'll sometimes get a subsample that gets a higher loss and you'll sometimes get a subsample with lower loss. This (partly) creates the fluctuations. You'll see less fluctuations if you use a larger minibatch size for the validation set (but it's more computations).

Comment: I am confused by the wording of this answer. Usually, for each epoch, the training loss is computed on each minibatch of the training set, and the average of these is reported at the end of the epoch. However, the validation  loss is reported over the entire validation set at the end of each epoch. An example can  be found [here](https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/main/imagenet/main.py).